# Android: seekbar in button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Button in my android application, and I need to expand it on click and display a Seekbar inside it, like at the picture below. What is the best practice to do that?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to handle tap of button to set visiblility of seekbar invisible if visible or visible if invisible.

```
 Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
 Seekbar seek = (Seekbar) findViewById(R.id.seek); 


  click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (seek.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { 
         seek.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
            } else { 
                seek.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }
        }

  });
```